# How does a constant opcode become negative in Script

Tags: script, sequence

I am doing some tutorial and in this chapter we are suppose to reproduce the Script scripting language

I am struggling to understand one of the exercises, here it is:

```
Create a ScriptSig that can unlock this ScriptPubKey:
767695935687
```

and the answer is 0x52 so that :

```
>>> from script import Script
>>> script_pubkey = Script([0x76, 0x76, 0x95, 0x93, 0x56, 0x87])
>>> script_sig = Script([0x52])
>>> combined_script = script_sig + script_pubkey
>>> print(combined_script.evaluate(0))
```

and that `OP_2 or 52 will satisfy the equation x² + x – 6 = 0.`

I guess I get the whole part execution except when the OP_6 is pushed on the stack, how does it become negative ?

Comment: It doesn't. The script implements "x^2 + x = 6". The last opcode is OP_EQUAL. Of course, the script cannot work because it uses the disabled opcode OP_MUL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not sure how it would work there but it is in fact basic arithmetic, we have this `x^2 + x = 6` then we substract 6 from both sides `x^2 + x - 6 = 6 - 6` then we simplify `x^2 + x - 6 = 0`